# Setting moodle online

Tags: moodle

Good day everyone, I have been trying to put my moodle online so pcs from internet can access it, but until now, no luck at all. (Im using moodle 2.3.2 on Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7).

I tried to configure the moodle file config.php, setting the directive $CFG -> wwwroot = "my-public-ip/moodle". Then, when I access to moodel from the server, I can access it by "http://my-public-ip/moodle", when I  try to access via localhost, it sends an error which it is OK.

But the funny part comes when I try to access the server from an outside pc. When I type "http://my-public-ip/moodle" it simply cant "see" the configuration I made to the config.php file (it says: This server cna only be accessed via localhost/moodle) it looks like the outside pcs are either ignoring it, or searching for another configuration file. I dont know what the hell is happening, this is very odd.

Any ideas?? tnx!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following file:

> lib-->setuplib.php

```
Redirect ($CFG->wwwroot, get_string('wwwrootmismatch', 'error', $CFG->wwwroot), 3);
```

for

```
Redirect ($CFG->wwwroot, get_string('wwwrootmismatch', 'error', $CFG->wwwroot), 0);
```

Comment: changing lib to achieve something that is configurable is really a bad idea. dunno why this answer got accepted, but this is not the proper way and is kind of risky. it's better to avoid that way, mentioned replace tool is the proper way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but it's also worth pointing out you may need to also run the database search and replace script, at:

http://my-public-ip/moodle/admin/tool/replace/index.php

as referenced in Method 2 [here](https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Moodle_migration).

This is required if you **change** the name of the site once you have installed it. If you were already using Moodle under "localhost", then there will be a number of references to the old localhost address stored in the database that need to be updated to the new IP-based address.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the http:// part is missing?

```
$CFG->wwwroot = "my-public-ip/moodle"
```

should be

```
$CFG->wwwroot = "http://my-public-ip/moodle"
```

Comment: no. see answer from @MartinGreenaway, he explains what must be done. however, http:// part might also be essential.